# Ionic 3 Wrap text from variables

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm building a chat page, The chat messages are stored in a database at the server. When a user opens the chat page, I retrieve the chat history from the server and load it at the screen.

The Problem is with wrapping long texts. "text-wrap" (ionic property) and CSS "word-wrap: break-word;" works fine on static text on the page but doesn't work on the dynamic text that comes from the server.

Chat Page HTML

```
<ion-content #content padding text-wrap>
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let message of messages" no-lines text-wrap>
  <div *ngIf="message.status == '1'">
    <h3 class="left-message">
      <span>{{ message.sms }}</span>
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="message.status == '2'">
    <h3 class="right-message">
      <span>{{ message.sms }}</span>
    </h3>
  </div>
</ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

What I want to achieve is to wrap the text from {{message.sms}}.

UPDATE:-

CSS Code

```
 .left-message{
    color:white;
    float: left;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
 .left-message span {
    background-color: rgb(127, 166, 245);
    margin-top:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    display:flex;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
 .right-message{
    color:grey;
    white-space: normal;
    float:right;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
 .right-message span {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(216,216,217);
    margin-top:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px;
    display:flex;
    white-space: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
 }
```

Comment: show your css of class left-message and right-message

Comment: updated code thx.